# Embed Google Maps list of places in website

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I know Google Maps lets you embed specific places using an `<iframe>` HTML object, but the embedded map is limited to just a single location. Is there any way to embed a list of locations that I created on Google Maps into a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### want this result?

[image]

---

## here the the list to do to have this

1. go to google MYMAPS *https://www.google.com/maps/d/*
2. click the red button "CREATE NEW MAP"

[image]

3. rename the map, if you want [image]
4. now click the icon for choosing your desiderated place

[image]

5. do it for 2 or times (in my chase I do it for 3 times)
6. click the **preview button**

[image]

7. now you will have 3 cities or places
   [image]
8. click **share button**

[image]

9. now click **get code to embed in my website**

[image]

10. set to public this.
11. now you have embedded code

[image]

## finally you have a maps embed with more places assigned

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1RK0XAw_xdwqvXzdk2tibWWrqKoXpza53&ehbc=2E312F" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: Found a potential edge case issue  with this method. When signed in to a Google Account with a cancelled workspace subscription the maps doesn't show, instead I see "We are sorry, but you have cancelled your subscription to Google Workspace. You will need to re-subscribe to Google Workspace in order to use Google Workspace services like Google Drive." Logging out resolves it. Haven't found a fix\workaround.